# What is the modulus of a number?

Tags: terminology, complex-numbers, absolute-value

What is the exact definition of the modulus of a number? As far as I know, it is the distance between the origin and the point associated with this number. So if $z=a+bi \in \Bbb C,|z|=OM=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ where M is the point with affix $z$. By extending this definition to split-complex numbers, we should have $z=a+bj$ and $|z|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$. But the modulus of a split-complex number is given by $|z|=\sqrt{a^2-b^2}$. Where this formula come from and what does it represents?

Comment: What's a split-complex number?

Comment: @StefanSmith Split-Complexes are numbers of the form $a+bj$ where a and are reals and $j^2=+1, j≠1, j≠-1$. They look mostly like complex numbers with different properties.

Comment: Thanks.  I can see the that the set of split-complex numbers is a ring.  Is that ring isomorphic to anything that is better-known?  I have never heard of split-complex numbers before>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The modulus can also be written as

$$|z|^2 = z\overline{z}.$$

In the split-complex numbers, if we have $z = a+bj$, then

$$|z|^2 = (a+bj)(a-bj) = a^2+abj-abj-b^2j^2 = a^2-b^2$$

since $j^2 = +1$.

Thus, $|z| = \sqrt{a^2-b^2}.$

For complex numbers, you can see how $-b^2i^2$ becomes $+b^2$.

---

For complex numbers, the notion between "modulus" and "size" goes through the notion that the modulus is a norm, and norms and sizes are intuitively linked.

For the split-complex numbers, the modulus is not a norm, so the link between modulus and size does not exist.

Rather, think of modulus as something that has a handy property that $|zw| = |z||w|$.

Comment: When you say _the modulus can also written as..._ you are using a property of the modulus and not it's definition. The properties can  differ from a set to another whereas the definition should _always_ be respected. So you can't define $|z|=\sqrt{z\bar z}$

Comment: Actually, that's precisely how the modulus is defined for split-complex numbers. Really, it's also how it's defined for complex numbers, too. It's just that the idea "modulus = norm" in $\Bbb C$ is so intuitive that we often present it in the reverse way, and present the conjugate property as a consequence. But there's no *a priori* reason for the modulus to be a norm, that is just a convenience in $\Bbb C$. The crucial property we desire in a modulus is $|zw| = |z||w|$.

Comment: One way to see this is to experiment using the Euclidean norm in place of the modulus. See which theorems break!